# RadioButtonをEnabled = Falseにした時にForeColorは変更せずにグレーアウトしたい

Tags: vb.net

- 実現したいこと
  VB.NET(VisualStudio2005)で既存システムの改修を行っています。
  RadioButtonをFalseにした時に、文字色(ForeColor)は変更させずにグレーアウトさせたいです。(以下の画像）
  ・Enabled = True
  [image: 実現したい RadioButton Enabled = True]
  ・Enabled = False
  [image: 実現したい RadioButton Enabled = False]
- 発生している問題
  RadioButtonのプロパティを「Enabled = False」に設定すると、文字色(ForeColor)が変更されてしまう。(以下の画像）
  ・Enabled = True
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
  ・Enabled = False
  [image: RadioButtonをEnabled = Falseに設定]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/151341

Comment: 解決済みなら自己回答をされては。　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtonのテキスト上にLabelを貼り付けることで解決